# App misidentifies Unity Answers links as StackExchange Qs, resulting in "Loading the Question Failed"

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, hyperlinks

Frequently comments in GameDev.SE will point to similar questions that have been asked on [answers.unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html) (a similar Q&A site run by the creators of the Unity game engine)

Example: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15453/how-to-make-a-user-interface-form.html

When clicked on in the Android app, the app seems to try to parse these link as though they were internal links to other StackExchange questions, displaying a "Loading the question failed" error dialog when accessing the question fails.

**Expected behaviour:** the app should treat the link like other non-StackExchange web links, and attempt to open the page in the default web browser.

Edit: I observed this today in version 1.0.68 on Android 5.1.1

Comment: Repro'd on SE app v1.0.68. Interesting case. It makes me wonder if the app parse the link with `/questions/` as SE sites... **Edit**: here is the link, http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15453/how-to-make-a-user-interface-form.html, in case that question is deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this, it's fixed as of version 1.0.69. An embarrassing bug, to be honest, debug versions of the app were even logging "Attempting to load unknown site: answers.unity3d.com".